# trace of a L^2 function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am working on a proof but I am stuck on one thing. Long story short, is there any tensor valued Hilbert space like:

\begin{align}
S=\{\boldsymbol{T}\in (L^2(\Omega))_{\text{sym}}^{3\times3}:\boldsymbol{T}\hat{n}\in (L^2(\partial\Omega))^3\}
\end{align}

If that is not possible, is there any information about the dual operator of a tensor-valued Hilbert space where the original space has the norm

\begin{align}
\|\boldsymbol{T}\|^2=\int_{\Omega}|\boldsymbol{T}|^2\text{dx }+\int_{\Omega}|\text{div }\boldsymbol{T}|^2\text{ dx}
\end{align}

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense to consider spaces of $L^2$ functions with $L^2$ boundary traces. $L^2$ functions have no meaningful boundary values.

Comment: I know it doesn't in principle because of the definition of trace. However, I wanted to avoid the use the norm described at the bottom of the question since I know very little about the properties of such space.